# Authorization in PHP doesn't work1

Tags: php

The page displays this registration and the input works fine, but when I go in, this thing does not change.

[image]

indexv3.php

```php
<?php
require "db.php";
require "index.php";
?>
```

db.php

```php
<?php
require "libs/rb.php";
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project','root','');
session_start();
```

login,sign up and logout worked, but index.php doesn't work.

```php
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])): ?>
    Hi,<?php echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login;?>
    <hr>
    <a href="logout.php">Exit</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="login.php">Log In</a><br>
    <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you ever set `$_SESSION['logged_user']` anywhere?

Comment: in login.php in signup.php in logout.php

Comment: Then show that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you should start your session when the user accesses the login page.

Simply put session_start() at the first line of login.php and in the logout.php simply put session_destroy().

Hope this helps.